# Add to Homescreen Feature On Android 11

Tags: android, kotlin, intentfilter, android-launcher, android-11

I am try to build a similar functionality to the one on the Android Launcher that allows it to add web page shortcuts to home screen when the "Add to Homescreen" button is clicked on chrome.

After going through the code implementation of the feature on ["Launcher3"](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3/), I learn't that I have to use the `android.content.pm.action.CONFIRM_PIN_SHORTCUT` intent-filter which I did.

Which seems to work well on devices with Android API < 30 but the view/layout in the Intent filter handler activity don't show up in Android 11 (Except in the layout Inspector on Android Studio).

[image]

I have also seen this same feature work properly on Android 11 in Launcher3 based launchers such as [Rootless Launcher](https://github.com/amirzaidi/Launcher3),[Lawnchair](https://github.com/LawnchairLauncher/lawnchair/blob/11-dev/src/com/android/launcher3/dragndrop/AddItemActivity.java) and [Lean Launcher](https://github.com/hundeva/Lean-Launcher)

Here's my Implementation Below:

AndroidMainfest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.nurudroid.prime">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Prime">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER_APP" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AddShortcutActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:autoRemoveFromRecents="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppItemActivityTheme"
            android:label="Add PWA"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.pm.action.CONFIRM_PIN_SHORTCUT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

styles.xml

```
 <style name="AddShortcutTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

AddShortcutActivity.kt

```
 class AddShortcutActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       val mRequest = getPinItemRequest(intent)
        if (mRequest == null) {
            finish()
            return
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_shortcut)


        if (mRequest.requestType == PinItemRequest.REQUEST_TYPE_SHORTCUT) {
            setupShortcut()
        }
    }

    private fun setupShortcut() {}

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    fun getPinItemRequest(intent: Intent): PinItemRequest? {
        val extra = intent.getParcelableExtra<Parcelable>(LauncherApps.EXTRA_PIN_ITEM_REQUEST)
        return if (extra is PinItemRequest) extra else null
    }
}
```

activity_add_shortcut.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clipToPadding="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:paddingLeft="24dp"
                android:paddingRight="24dp"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:text="Hold and Drag to add to Homescreen" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp" >
        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@android:string/cancel" />
        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add Automatically" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE:**
After following the link in *Martin Zeitler's* comment and extracting some of the code,the Dialog to add Shortcut to homescreen shows up but only on second try, for the first time the dialog shows only in the LayoutInspector(See Gif below):

[image: Dialog shows only when clicked the second time]

[image: Shows in LayoutInspector the first time]

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.pm.shortcutlauncherdemo">


    <application android:label="@string/app_title"
        android:resizeableActivity="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <activity android:name="ShortcutLauncherMain"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="PinShortcutConfirm"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Dialog"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="false"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.pm.action.CONFIRM_PIN_SHORTCUT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

PinShortcutConfirm.kt

```
class PinShortcutConfirm : Activity(), View.OnClickListener {
private lateinit var mLauncherApps: LauncherApps
private lateinit var mRequest: PinItemRequest
private var mShortcutInfo: ShortcutInfo? = null
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.pin_shortcut_confirm)
    mLauncherApps = getSystemService(LauncherApps::class.java)
    findViewById<View>(R.id.ok).setOnClickListener(this)
    findViewById<View>(R.id.cancel).setOnClickListener(this)

    mRequest = getSystemService(LauncherApps::class.java)
        .getPinItemRequest(intent)
    mShortcutInfo = mRequest.shortcutInfo

    val description = findViewById<View>(R.id.shortcut_description) as TextView
    description.text = """
        ID: ${mShortcutInfo!!.id}
        Label: ${mShortcutInfo!!.shortLabel}
        """.trimIndent()
    val icon = mLauncherApps.getShortcutIconDrawable(mShortcutInfo!!, 0)
    if (icon != null) {
        (findViewById<View>(R.id.image) as ImageView).setImageDrawable(icon)
    }
}

override fun onClick(v: View) {
    when (v.id) {
        R.id.ok -> {
            acceptShortcut()
            finish()
        }
        R.id.cancel -> finish()
    }
}

private fun acceptShortcut() {
    val result = mRequest.accept()
    Log.i(TAG, "Accept returned: $result")
}

companion object {
    private const val TAG = "ShortcutConfirm"
}
```

}

pin_shortcut_confirm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <!-- Message to show to use. -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="48dip"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dip"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shortcut_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="@string/pin_shortcut_message"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <!-- Alert dialog style buttons along the bottom. -->
    <LinearLayout
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:measureWithLargestChild="true">
        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:id="@+id/ok"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@android:string/ok" />
        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@android:string/cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How about writing `fun setupShortcut()`, to begin with? See https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_development/tree/master/samples/ShortcutDemo

Comment: The problem is that the layout from the  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_shortcut)` isn't showing on screen at all. The `setupShortcut()` would have no effect on it.